# "create or replace trigger" not available on AWS RDS/Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_commands
    AFTER INSERT ON commands
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_commands_change();
```

it works on a local Postgres instance, but fails on AWS with:

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "TRIGGER"

however, if I remove the 'OR REPLACE' part:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_commands
    AFTER INSERT ON commands
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_commands_change();
```

then RDS accepts it. Why is that? and what would be the best way to update the trigger at every code restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely a Postgresql version mismatch, `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER` works only on Postgresql 14 (see documentation, [14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtrigger.html) and [13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtrigger.html)).

I'd suggest to use `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS` then `CREATE TRIGGER` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: that was exactly it; thanks

Comment: The full command should be the following:
`DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_commands ON commands;`